# Simple React JS tsx with Material UI throws an error, any ideas what's wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

This basic React code using Material components throws an error "View Config getter callback for component 'style' must be a function, any idea what's wrong with the code:

```
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  return (
    <Badge badgeContent={4} color="primary">
      <MailIcon color="action" />
    </Badge>
  );
}
```

```
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

This error is located at:
    in style (created by Insertion)
    in Insertion (created by MuiSvgIconRoot)
    in MuiSvgIconRoot
    in SvgIcon
    in MailIcon
    in span (created by MuiBadgeRoot)
    in MuiBadgeRoot
    in Badge (created by TabTwoScreen)
    in TabTwoScreen
    in Unknown (created by Route(two))
    in Route (created by Route(two))
    in Route(two) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator
    in Unknown (created by TabLayout)
    in TabLayout
    in Unknown (created by Route((tabs)))
    in Route (created by Route((tabs)))
    in Route((tabs)) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator
    in Unknown (created by RootLayoutNav)
    in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayoutNav)
    in RootLayoutNav (created by RootLayout)
    in RootLayout
    in Try
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by wrapper)
    in wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `path` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
```

Answer (score 2):

MUI is for React for the web; it looks like you're trying to use it in a React Native application. I don't think that works; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61398426/25507).